# How to get filename with argparse while specifying type=FileType(...) for this argument

Tags: python, file, argparse

Using the `type` parameter of the `argparse.add_argument` method, you can require an argument to be a readable file:

```
parser.add_argument('--sqlite-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

As a benefit of specifying this type, argparse checks whether the file can be read and displays an error to the user if not.

Is there a way to obtain the passed filename instead of an instance of `io.TextIOWrapper` or `io.BufferedReader`?

Since the filename appears in the string representation of the parser (`'sqlite_file': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='data/export.sqlite' ...`, or `'sqlite_file': <_io.BufferedReader name='data/export.sqlite' ...>`) it should be possible.

How to do it?

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue13824 looks into the possibility of `FileTYpe` checking without actually opening the file.  The solution I proposed there was to use `os.access` to test the filename.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, use the [`.name` attribute](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO.name) on the file object.

Demo:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--sqlite-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--sqlite-file'], dest='sqlite_file', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=FileType('r'), choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--sqlite-file', '/tmp/demo.db'])
>>> args.sqlite_file
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/demo.db' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> args.sqlite_file.name
'/tmp/demo.db'
```

Comment: What will happen, if user will specify `FileType` argument as `-` to use the stdin or stdout?

Comment: `FileType()` produces normal file objects for filenames, and `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout` for `'-'`. Those two objects have `'<stdin>'` and `'<stdout>'` as their name attribute, respectively.